# Getting machine information using WMI in 64-bit architecture

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, wmi

I'm trying to get some data about the current machine using C#. Currently I'm using `ManagementObjectCollection` to retrieve the information but it only works in 32-bits machines, not in 64-bit machines. Using the `Win32 Registry API` it is enough to read the correct data by passing the `RegistryView.Registry64` parameter but I don't know how to do this with WMI classes. Any help will be appreciated! Thank you. Here's a sample code I've tried:

```
private static void GetInformation()
{
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher windowsObject = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS"))
    {
        using (ManagementObjectCollection collection = windowsObject.Get())
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in collection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Install Date:{0}", managementObject["InstallDate"]);
                Console.WriteLine("OS Version: {0}.{1} Build {2}", managementObject["Version"], managementObject["BuildNumber"], managementObject["CodeSet"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Product Id: {0}", managementObject["SerialNumber"]);
            }
        }
    }

    using (ManagementObjectSearcher windowsObject = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT ProcessorID From Win32_processor"))
    {
        using (ManagementObjectCollection collection = windowsObject.Get())
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in collection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Processor Id: {0}", managementObject["ProcessorID"]);
            }
        }
    }

    using (ManagementObjectSearcher windowsObject = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT SerialNumber From Win32_BaseBoard"))
    {
        using (ManagementObjectCollection collection = windowsObject.Get())
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in collection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Motherboard Id: {0}", managementObject["SerialNumber"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you compiling your project as ..? are you doing it as `x64` or `x86 or AnyCpu`..?

Comment: I'm compiling as AnyCPU, as far as I know the .NET framework will run in 64 bit mode or 32 properly according to the machine architecture.

Comment: have you at least tried it..

Comment: That should work fine on x64, what happens when you run it?

Comment: It gives me incorrect/empty information, but finally I decided to work with both, `Registry` classes for OS information and `ManagementObjects` for hardware information.